# Now that marijuana is legal in several countries, do any states plan to legalize further drugs?

Tags: drugs

While marijuana is still illegal in the US due to federal law, several US states and Uruguay have passed laws unbanning it. Canada would also legalize it soon and I assume most of the world would make it legal within a decade.

I'm wondering if other drugs are also in the pipeline for full legalization? Perhaps some countries want to legalize cocaine to harm the cartels?

Please restrict your answers to statements made by government officials or government organizations.

Comment: _"I'm wondering if other drugs"_ Can you clearly define what you mean by "drugs"?

Comment: @guest271314 stuff like cocaine, LSD, MDMA, etc

Comment: You really need to clarify if for medicinal purposes or merely for non-prescription ("entertainment") purposes. Psychedelics (LSD, MDMA etc.) are being considered for the former but not the latter purpose. I guess you mean the latter with "full legalization", but keep in mind that cannabis is still restricted (in terms of quantities, whom it can be sold to [residents only] etc.) in Uruguay. Not sure about Canada's new law.

Comment: Restricting answers to comments by government officials really doesn't work in the US, since 8 of 9 states legalized marijuana via ballot initiative https://ballotpedia.org/History_of_marijuana_on_the_ballot (and several other states will have measures on their ballots this year).  It seems likely that legalization of other drugs would follow the same path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a government organisation, but there is a group of law enforcement officers advocating the end of the war on drugs. They don't seem to mention a specific type of narcotic, instead they refer to drugs in general. From their [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Enforcement_Action_Partnership):

> The Law Enforcement Action Partnership (LEAP), formerly Law Enforcement Against Prohibition, is a U.S.-based 501(c)(3) nonprofit group of current and former police, judges, prosecutors, and other criminal justice professionals who use their expertise to advance drug policy and criminal justice solutions that enhance public safety.

One of their key issues, also from their [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Enforcement_Action_Partnership#The_War_on_Drugs) (emphasis is mine):

> LEAP pushes to end the War on Drugs **and legalize and regulate all drugs from a public health perspective** as a means of reducing death, disease, and addiction associated with drug use and illegal drug sales.

Obviously, these people are not in charge of making the laws. Instead their jobs are enforcement-related. They are, however, familiar with the matter (given their professions) and as such it might be conceivable that their ideas spread to those who make the laws (possibly by shaping public opinion or through lobbying law makers).